# OpenShot image animation issue

Tags: animation, video, openshot

I created a fractal animation using JWildfire.  It consists of 5772 1024x768 still images.  I tried importing all of the images into OpenShot one step and had serious problems.  So, I broke it down the three "parts" of 1924 images apiece.  That was still problematic, but I got the images imported.  However, only the first 1924 will animate and when I tried to do subsequent video frames like I did with the first 1924 images, OpenShot would indicate that the first image in the set was not valid.  However, I tested it and even resaved it and it would open in other apps without a problem.  So, I imported the last two sets of 1924 without creating the video frame (I don't recall the exact term) thinking that I could edit the first frame to include all 5772 images.  Apparently, I was wrong.  How can I fix this so that it will play through all 5772 images rather than just the first 1924?  The PC that I have is far from top notch.  Here are my specs:

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3225 CPU @ 3.30GHz   3.30 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.88 GB usable)
Device ID   87BC0DCC-B603-4158-9700-09CEF99A171C
Product ID  00330-80000-00000-AA170
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎7/‎11/‎2020
OS build    19044.1503
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3740.0

I'm using OpenShot 2.6.1 64-bit.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing Shotcut.  It made creating three separate image sequences and adding them to a timeline trivial.  Now, the animation plays through seamlessly just as it should.  Shotcut seems to be written much better.  It doesn't take up nearly as much RAM with all 5772 images loaded.  It wasn't anywhere near as problematic to get all of those images loaded and creating the three image sequences was super easy.  The UI isn't very "shiny", but it gets the job done.  So, goodbye OpenShot and hello Shotcut!  Oh, and the xml/mlt movie file is much smaller than the osp movie file.  So, that's awesome too.